# Influx1.2 (or 0.9+) JOIN among several measurements

Tags: mysql, influxdb

The author has stated that: SQL JOINs aren’t available for InfluxDB measurements; your schema design should reflect that difference.

But what if we really wanna use 'JOIN' functions?

Say I have a database `mydb`, with several measurements `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, each with field keys `id`, therefore we are interested in given a `id`, output data that is `merged` with `m1`, `m2`, `m3`.

Is it really impossible to do this under 0.9+? Or we just have to put all information into only 1 measurement and then do the query?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InfluxDB Joining Series for 0.8 version](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/api/query_language/#joining-series)

If that doesn't help , then I believe you need to implement 'JOIN' function in your own code.

Below is taken from Influxdb documentation-

```
 It is possible to query more than one measurement at once
 using regular expressions. 
 However, every field referenced in the query must be present
 in each measurement and cannot be filtered by measurement.
```

More info at [InfluxDB 0.9 vs 0.8](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/concepts/08_vs_09/)

Let me know, if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though 0.8 was abandoned and we are focusing on 0.9+.... anyway thanks!

Comment: @tclo2, please upvote my answer if u find it useful/